# Javascript API for Office error

Tags: javascript, office

I am trying to read from an excel file to use the data in SharePoint.  I recently discovered the Javascript API for Office however I can't reference the library without an error.  I use the following html reference:

`<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js"/>`

My browser responds with Uncaught TypeError: window.external.GetContext is not a function.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The [script element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) can't be self-closed.
Try
`<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js"></script>`